# Xamarin.Forms UWP - To deploy this app, your deployment target should be running Windows Universal Run-time version 10.0.16299.0 or higher

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have created new Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio 2017. And trying to run UWP application and ended up with below error.

> To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running
>   Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.16299.0 or higher. You
>   currently are running version 10.0.14393.2214. Please update your OS,
>   or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate
>   version.

Comment: Have you tried to update windows ? Or simply lower build minimum widows version in your project?

Comment: I just created a fresh VS2017 xamarin forms project & it gives me this error. I've tried changing all the min & target versions. But still gives the same error.

Comment: When you create xamarin forms you select the os version, by default it's the most recent version,which means it's higher then your running is. You should be able to change uwp project deployment version of app (I would recommend to restart vs after that, I had ghost errors with xamarin forms ) and you should be able to run it, please also make sure that you have windows set in developer mode.

Comment: The windows is in developer mode. If i change the OS version, i'm facing a new error.  'netstandard2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586'.

Comment: 10.0.16299 is minimal uwp version for net standard 2.0. I would suggest the obvious - windows update. Even if you change standard version, you will still have issues since your os version is below v10.0.10586,which I assume is minimal that you can set

Comment: My OS version is 14393.2214. Do i need to update my OS to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes you should update your os

Comment: i updated my OS build version to 17134 & it's started working. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with your project, but with the PC you are trying to build it on. Maybe you have disabled updates, because apparently you still have Windows 10 Anniversary Update (14393) which is very old (current version is April 2018 Update (17134). To build apps with Fall Creators Update SDK (which is the first that supports .NET Standard 2.0.), you first have to update at least to that version of the operating system.

Go to system Settings, Update & Security and check for updates. There must be a lot of them waiting for you already. If not, use Windows 10 Update Assistant from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Comment: My OS is showing, your device is up to date. My OS version is 14393.2214. If i update my OS to 17134.286, The project will run?

Comment: Yes, it definitely should. I am not sure why you are not getting the option to update. Do you have your own PC or a company-based one? Maybe the company policy disallows the update, in which case it would be worth contacting IT support.

Comment: i updated my OS build version to 17134 & it's started working. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Awesome, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Solution explorer and double tap the properties

[image]

Then please select application options and select minimum build version based on your current OS build version. It works for me.

[image]